# How to scroll to an id from a navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I;m abegginer using javascript/jQuery, but I want to click on a navbar element and then scroll down the page to the id corresponding to it. (ids:  #home, #about, #portafolio, #contact)

Here's my navbar list:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
  </ul>
```

My attempt using https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/blob/master/README.md:

```
$('ul li').first().click().scrollTo('#home'); 
$('ul li').eq(1).click().scrollTo('#about'); 
$('ul li').eq(2).click().scrollTo('#portfolio'); 
$('ul li').eq(3).click().scrollTo('#contact');
```

Anyone can help me in how to even create a proper function for it to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without the use of jQuery. 
In the anchor tags in your navbar elements. put the id of the section in the href.

So something like

```
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a><li>
```

Here the 'about' and 'contact' are the ids of the about and contact section.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: Although, you can do it even with jQuery. lookup window.location.hash, but you shouldn't be complicating things.

Comment: I'm im still at the begginng stages of even html, thanks again ;/

Answer (score 0):

I will show you an example looking at which you can do necessary changes in your code.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

"#about","#services" etc are the ids given to the div.
Now on click of About link it will scroll to the particular div.